# Continuity of a continuous function and a converging sequence. Proof by induction.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a continuous function and $\{x_k\}$ a sequence converging to $x\in X$ as $k\longrightarrow \infty$. Prove by induction that if $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $f^n$ represents $f$ composed with itself $n$ times, then $f^n(x_k)$ converges to $f^n(x)$ as $k\longrightarrow \infty$.

I know how to do induction proofs i.e. base case, inductive Hypothesis, and inductive step but this one has me a little confused since I've never done one with a converging sequence.

I have $f(f(f...(f(x))...)=f^n(x)$ to represent $f$ composed with itself $n$ times. The let n=0 for the base case and if n=0 then my assumption would be to let $f^0(x)= x$ but feels like I am wrong. Also unsure what is the proper way to note the inductive hypothesis and if I can just use the above representation then go into the inductive step with $f^{n+1}(f(f...(f(x))...)=f^{n+1}(x)$.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You for any continuos function $x_n \to x$ implies $f(x_n)\to f(x)$. If $f:X\to Y$ and we can compose $f$ with itself, then $Y \subset X$. Now, it's clear $f^n(x)$ is a continuos function by composition.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition isn't wrong. For the case $n=1$ ($n =0$ would just be the identity function), you have to look at the limit
$\lim_{k\to \infty} f^{(1)}(x_k)$. Since $f$ is continuous, this certainly converges to $f(x)$.

Then for the induction step, you have to look at the limit $\lim_{k\to \infty} f^{(n+1)}(x_k)$, and use the continuity again.